# Wordpress get_posts() fetch posts with empty custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use the `get_posts()` function in Wordpress to retrieve a list of posts but only if they have an empty custom field, which is called `wpcf-translated-details`

Here is my current code:

```
    <?php
    require_once('wp-load.php');
    $temp_list_of_products_array        = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'sale', 'numberposts' => 10 ) );
    $temp_list_of_products_array_length = count( $temp_list_of_products_array );

    for ($xt = 0; $xt < $temp_list_of_products_array_length; $xt++) {
        $temp_product_id                    = $temp_list_of_products_array[$xt]->ID;
        $temp_product_untranslated_field    = get_post_meta($temp_product_id, 'wpcf-product-details', true);
        $temp_product_translated_field      = get_post_meta($temp_product_id, 'wpcf-translated-product-details', true);
        $temp_product_description_language  = 'en';

        if ($temp_product_translated_field == null) {
            $temp_product_translated_contents   = google_translate_text($temp_product_untranslated_field, $temp_product_description_language);
            update_post_meta($temp_product_id, 'wpcf-translated-product-details', $temp_product_translated_contents);
        } 
        echo $temp_product_id;
    }
    ?>
```

But I couldn't find any method or instructions on how to achieve this.

So my question is, how can I modify this code so that it only fetches 10 posts which have an empty `wpcf-translated-details` custom field?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `meta_query` parameter for `WP_Query` **[here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)**.

```
$posts = new WP_Query(
    array('post_type' => 'sale',
        'numberposts' => 10,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'wpcf-translated-details',
                'value' => '',
                'compare' => '=',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, is it not possible to use 'meta_query' in the get_posts() function?

Comment: I keep getting 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function WP_Query()' even though I've included 'include('wp-load.php');' in my php file

Comment: `WP_Query` is a class...you should have `$posts = new WP_Query()`. There's a typo in the answer above.

Comment: `meta_query` no. But `meta_key` and `meta_value` parameters yes. Check for examples: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Default_Usage

Comment: How do I get the ID of the fetched posts now? $temp_list_of_products_array[$xt]->ID doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: `var_dump($temp_list_of_products_array)` to see what structure do you have.

Comment: I'm getting no posts being returned using the above method. I managed to extract the post ID using the WP_Query method without the meta_query parameter. But when I include the meta_query paramter, then no posts get returned with empty custom fields even though there are a lot of posts with empty custom fields

Comment: What does it mean, empty custim field. Is it not exists, or it exits, just it is empty?

Comment: The field exist, just doesn't have any values